# Print output in one line and grouped Python

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, output

After running two of my loops:

```
for word in words:
    for i in range (1,p+1):
        print(word,len(re.findall(word, input_[i])),i)
```

I am getting example result like this:

```
businesses 0 1
businesses 0 2
businesses 2 3
```

But I would like achieve this:

```
businesses 0 1 0 2 2 3
```

I can get this result by this:

```
for word in words:
        print(word,len(re.findall(word, input_[i])),i,len(re.findall(word, input_[i+1])),i+1,len(re.findall(word, input_[i+2])),i+2)
```

But it's not the point because `p` can be dynamically changed so i don't want to use static values like `i+1 i+2`....

I will be gratefull for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example that includes definitions of `words`, `input_`, and `p`?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you add add `end=' '` in the end of your print function it will work fine.
as an example:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in L:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

the result will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

So simple! Thank you!
Finally my code looks like this:

```
for word in words:
    print(word,end=' ')
    for i in range (1,p+1):
        print("->",len(re.findall(word, input_[i])),i,end=' ')
    print('\n')
```